# What are all 3-letter (or shorter) words in Esperanto?

Tags: word-formation

**Is there a list of all Esperanto words of length 3 or less?** Please note that I am not asking about roots.

I am asking as a seasoned language learner: Short words can throw a learner off because

- their roots are often hard to discern (though this is presumably less so in Esperanto),
- they are easily confused with other short words (due to their length, every letter matters: it is harder to recover from mispronouncing or mishearing a single phoneme), and
- due to their duration they stand out less from other words (in spoken language).

I also believe that a full list won't be all that long (if the focus is on words in common use), so one might as well learn them all in one go.

If someone is willing to come up with such a list, that would be great. I am primarily interested in (possibly inflected) common-use lexemes, *not* in all possible lexemes that can be formed in a grammar-conformant way from commonly used roots and affixes. Such a list could even be corpus-based and annotated with frequencies (just an idea – not a requirement for answering this question).

Comment: Since most Esperanto words have an ending (o-nouns, a-adjectives, e-adverbs, plus a few verbal endings) you'll only find pronouns, prepositions, conjunctions and a few other things like them. If you look for those classes of words plus the "tabel-vortoj", you'll probably find all short words in the language.

Comment: @marcus I suspect in practice it's more difficult because there might be: exclamations with characteristic meanings, gender-neutral pronouns of more recent origin, words derived from 2-letter roots, etc. Of course not all possible words derived from 2-letter roots are in actual use (even though they are technically legal as ad-hoc formations), but that's why a list will come in handy.

Comment: OK, there's “teo” from a 2-letter root so these do exist after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's filter a spell-check dictionary, shall we?

The [nu](https://www.nushell.sh/) / [nix-shell](https://knezevic.ch/posts/nix-shell-redistributable-scripts/) script

```
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#!nix-shell -i nu
#!nix-shell -p nushell -p "aspellWithDicts (ps: [ ps.eo ])"
(
    aspell dump master eo
    | lines
    | split column '/' vorto vorto-tipo
    | where {|x| ($x.vorto | str length) <= 3}
)
```

produces the following list:

```
╭─────┬───────┬────────────╮
│   # │ vorto │ vorto-tipo │
├─────┼───────┼────────────┤
│   0 │ abs   │         ❎ │
│   1 │ ADA   │         ❎ │
│   2 │ Ada   │ A          │
│   3 │ AdE   │         ❎ │
│   4 │ aga   │ EOB        │
│   5 │ agi   │ BVO        │
│   6 │ AI    │         ❎ │
│   7 │ AIS   │         ❎ │
│   8 │ alo   │ AOX        │
│   9 │ ami   │ ABDMOTSY   │
│  10 │ ani   │ KFGQV      │
│  11 │ APL   │         ❎ │
│  12 │ ara   │ ACGLOQ     │
│  13 │ aso   │ AO         │
│  14 │ avo   │ F          │
│  15 │ aĥ    │         ❎ │
│  16 │ aŭ    │         ❎ │
│  17 │ ba    │ AO         │
│  18 │ bff   │         ❎ │
│  19 │ bv    │         ❎ │
│  20 │ ci    │ P          │
│  21 │ cia   │ T          │
│  22 │ cm    │         ❎ │
│  23 │ da    │         ❎ │
│  24 │ DBM   │         ❎ │
│  25 │ de    │         ❎ │
│  26 │ des   │         ❎ │
│  27 │ dia   │ KFCOZSYG   │
│  28 │ DIV   │         ❎ │
│  29 │ dm    │         ❎ │
│  30 │ DNA   │         ❎ │
│  31 │ DNS   │         ❎ │
│  32 │ do    │         ❎ │
│  33 │ DOS   │         ❎ │
│  34 │ dua   │ AOCGQX     │
│  35 │ eca   │ KAO        │
│  36 │ edo   │ AO         │
│  37 │ ega   │ AC         │
│  38 │ eja   │ AO         │
│  39 │ eki   │ GVX        │
│  40 │ ela   │ AGQX       │
│  41 │ emi   │ AOV        │
│  42 │ ena   │ AGQXOY     │
│  43 │ Eo    │ AO         │
│  44 │ era   │ AO         │
│  45 │ ESC   │         ❎ │
│  46 │ eta   │ ACOQUG     │
│  47 │ EU    │         ❎ │
│  48 │ eĉ    │         ❎ │
│  49 │ FBN   │         ❎ │
│  50 │ FE    │         ❎ │
│  51 │ FEL   │         ❎ │
│  52 │ feo   │ F          │
│  53 │ fia   │ AOXY       │
│  54 │ FK    │         ❎ │
│  55 │ FTP   │         ❎ │
│  56 │ gea   │ ACGQ       │
│  57 │ GNU   │         ❎ │
│  58 │ goa   │ AO         │
│  59 │ GUI   │         ❎ │
│  60 │ ha    │         ❎ │
│  61 │ he    │         ❎ │
│  62 │ hej   │         ❎ │
│  63 │ hm    │         ❎ │
│  64 │ ho    │         ❎ │
│  65 │ ia    │ AO         │
│  66 │ ial   │         ❎ │
│  67 │ IBM   │         ❎ │
│  68 │ ico   │ AO         │
│  69 │ ido   │ KFS        │
│  70 │ iea   │ A          │
│  71 │ ien   │         ❎ │
│  72 │ ies   │         ❎ │
│  73 │ igi   │ OTX        │
│  74 │ II    │         ❎ │
│  75 │ III   │         ❎ │
│  76 │ IJK   │         ❎ │
│  77 │ ila   │ KANOH      │
│  78 │ ili   │ P          │
│  79 │ IMS   │         ❎ │
│  80 │ ina   │ ACOU       │
│  81 │ IRC   │         ❎ │
│  82 │ iri   │ AGJLORT    │
│  83 │ ISO   │         ❎ │
│  84 │ iu    │ P          │
│  85 │ IV    │         ❎ │
│  86 │ IX    │         ❎ │
│  87 │ ja    │         ❎ │
│  88 │ jc    │         ❎ │
│  89 │ je    │         ❎ │
│  90 │ ju    │         ❎ │
│  91 │ kaj   │         ❎ │
│  92 │ kc    │         ❎ │
│  93 │ ke    │         ❎ │
│  94 │ kg    │         ❎ │
│  95 │ kia   │ AO         │
│  96 │ kiu   │ P          │
│  97 │ km    │         ❎ │
│  98 │ KOI   │         ❎ │
│  99 │ kos   │         ❎ │
│ 100 │ kot   │         ❎ │
│ 101 │ kp    │         ❎ │
│ 102 │ ks    │         ❎ │
│ 103 │ ktp   │         ❎ │
│ 104 │ kuo   │ AO         │
│ 105 │ l'    │         ❎ │
│ 106 │ la    │         ❎ │
│ 107 │ li    │ P          │
│ 108 │ LKK   │         ❎ │
│ 109 │ ln    │         ❎ │
│ 110 │ log   │         ❎ │
│ 111 │ LR    │         ❎ │
│ 112 │ lui   │ AGOT       │
│ 113 │ mi    │ P          │
│ 114 │ mll   │         ❎ │
│ 115 │ mm    │         ❎ │
│ 116 │ mod   │         ❎ │
│ 117 │ mu    │         ❎ │
│ 118 │ muo   │ AOX        │
│ 119 │ ne    │         ❎ │
│ 120 │ nei   │ AOV        │
│ 121 │ nek   │         ❎ │
│ 122 │ ni    │ P          │
│ 123 │ NLM   │         ❎ │
│ 124 │ Noa   │ A          │
│ 125 │ NP    │         ❎ │
│ 126 │ NS    │         ❎ │
│ 127 │ nu    │         ❎ │
│ 128 │ oda   │ AO         │
│ 129 │ oka   │ AXO        │
│ 130 │ ol    │         ❎ │
│ 131 │ omo   │ AO         │
│ 132 │ ona   │ ACOG       │
│ 133 │ oni   │ P          │
│ 134 │ opa   │ ANO        │
│ 135 │ ori   │ AOYCGQTJ   │
│ 136 │ ova   │ AOHY       │
│ 137 │ PAG   │         ❎ │
│ 138 │ pi    │         ❎ │
│ 139 │ pia   │ ACOQMUY    │
│ 140 │ PIV   │         ❎ │
│ 141 │ PK    │         ❎ │
│ 142 │ PL    │         ❎ │
│ 143 │ poa   │ AX         │
│ 144 │ pro   │         ❎ │
│ 145 │ pt    │         ❎ │
│ 146 │ PV    │         ❎ │
│ 147 │ pĝ    │         ❎ │
│ 149 │ ree   │ P          │
│ 150 │ REU   │         ❎ │
│ 151 │ RFC   │         ❎ │
│ 152 │ RTF   │         ❎ │
│ 153 │ RVB   │         ❎ │
│ 154 │ SAT   │         ❎ │
│ 155 │ se    │         ❎ │
│ 156 │ sed   │         ❎ │
│ 157 │ seo   │ AO         │
│ 158 │ SEU   │         ❎ │
│ 159 │ si    │ P          │
│ 160 │ SSE   │         ❎ │
│ 161 │ tan   │         ❎ │
│ 162 │ tea   │ AOZH       │
│ 163 │ TeX   │         ❎ │
│ 164 │ tg    │         ❎ │
│ 165 │ tia   │ AYO        │
│ 166 │ tiu   │ P          │
│ 167 │ TTT   │         ❎ │
│ 168 │ UEA   │         ❎ │
│ 169 │ uja   │ AO         │
│ 170 │ UK    │         ❎ │
│ 171 │ ula   │ CF         │
│ 172 │ um    │         ❎ │
│ 173 │ uma   │ AOY        │
│ 174 │ UN    │         ❎ │
│ 175 │ ura   │ AO         │
│ 176 │ URL   │         ❎ │
│ 177 │ USD   │         ❎ │
│ 178 │ UTF   │         ❎ │
│ 179 │ uzi   │ ADROUYT    │
│ 180 │ vd    │         ❎ │
│ 181 │ vea   │ AOVX       │
│ 182 │ VGA   │         ❎ │
│ 183 │ VI    │         ❎ │
│ 184 │ vi    │ P          │
│ 185 │ VII   │         ❎ │
│ 186 │ XI    │         ❎ │
│ 187 │ XII   │         ❎ │
│ 188 │ XIV   │         ❎ │
│ 189 │ XIX   │         ❎ │
│ 190 │ XML   │         ❎ │
│ 191 │ XV    │         ❎ │
│ 192 │ XVI   │         ❎ │
│ 193 │ XX    │         ❎ │
│ 194 │ zoo   │ AO         │
│ 195 │ ĥi    │         ❎ │
│ 196 │ ĉe    │         ❎ │
│ 197 │ ĉi    │         ❎ │
│ 198 │ ĝi    │ P          │
│ 199 │ ŝi    │ P          │
├─────┼───────┼────────────┤
│   # │ vorto │ vorto-tipo │
╰─────┴───────┴────────────╯
```

As you can see, there's quite some abbreviations (such as acronyms and initialisms) as well as roman numerals. Also, some important short words, such as the possessive forms of the personal pronouns are missing, probably because the spell-checker would generate them on-the-fly based on the grammar/word-building rules it knows.

Nonetheless, this might be a good starting point for further processing.

Answer (score 2):

La listo dependas de lingvouzo. En familia kunteksto, ekkri(ec)aj vortoj kiel `ek`, `fuŝ` estas vortoj (kaj radikoj).

Vi povus kontroli Tekstaro.com, nur kelkaj tekstoj partoprenas la kolekton kaj tio donos al vi ideon pri la uzo de tiaj vortoj. Serĉo ne rekte produktos liston, sed per iom da aldona laboro oni povus ĝin krei.

Ekzemple, [tiu ĉi ligilo](https://tekstaro.com/?s=63fe62e29dd5a) listigos ĉiujn triliterajn vortojn (aŭ vorte uzitajn radikojn) en la elektitaj verkoj.

Sed vi ne ofte trovos aferojn kiel `mio` ekzemple. Krei kompletan liston postulos esploradon en vortaroj, tekstoj, konon de la lingvo kaj konsideron de la parolata lingvo, kongresa, renkontiĝa kaj familia.